# node server for socket.io does not find localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have following code in my server.js file

```
var mongo  = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    client = require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;
```

When I execute `node server.js` then it does not show anything on terminal. When I type `http://localhost:8080` in browser then in browser console I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

**Why and how can I fix this problem?**

Comment: Are you actually running a webserver somewhere in that `server.js` file or is that literally the contents of the file? Baring in mind `socket.io` is a *socket* library, not a webserver, that's why  `http://localhost:8080` doesn't work. Have you read the [docs](http://socket.io/docs/)?

Comment: That is the whole code in that file.

Comment: Entire code could be found here which works. https://github.com/rcadaoas/phpAcademy-Node.js-Real-time-chat/tree/master/Codes

Comment: This isn't going to work for numerous reasons, see the docs I linked to for socket.io that will get you started.

Comment: Actually it could also be used the way I am doing(but slightly different) according to documentation here http://socket.io/docs/#restricting-yourself-to-a-namespace

Answer (score 0):

The service is running on port 8080, but there is no resource for the service to return/load hence the 404. I replicated your error just to see if there was something I was missing. If there was nothing running on port 8080 you would get something like `Webpage unavailable`. Try looking through the docs and giving the server something to return. You stated yourself that the [entire code](https://github.com/rcadaoas/phpAcademy-Node.js-Real-time-chat/tree/master/Codes) works, so go from there. Those two lines alone are not going to serve anything on their own.